# Count repeated values - help my mysql query is dead slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Lets say I have a table like this:

```
Id*|value
```

For each `Id` I want to count how many times the corresponding `value` exist. Like with this sample data:

```
1, a
2, b
3, a 
4, b
5, c
6, a
```

I want:

```
1, a, 3
2, b, 2
3, a, 3
4, b, 2
5, c, 1
6, a, 3
```

This is what I have right now and I believe it is working, but it is dead slow:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.value, COUNT(t2.value) FROM `table` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `table` AS t2 ON (t1.value = t2.value)
GROUP by t1.Id
```

My table contains hounded of thousands rows. Any suggestion on how to improve this performance vice?

Comment: Your query return too: 3, a, 1; 6, a, 1 and so on... peraphs is slow because your result is not correct?

Comment: Your comment does not make sense?

Comment: Dear, you've written your output, but some tuples isn't show. So I think you have jumped some of them. So your query returns more rows your aspected.

Comment: Sorry I believe you are wrong, notice I have group by id

Comment: Yes, because you use MySql but if you use another DBMS you can't put in select field list a field not present in group by and not in aggregate function (as t1.value)

Comment: Have you do you have an index on value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.value, t2.cnt FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT value, COUNT(value) as cnt 
    FROM Table1 GROUP BY value
) AS t2 ON (t1.value = t2.value)
ORDER BY t1.Id
```

OR

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.value,COUNT(t2.id) AS cnt FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table1 AS t2
   ON  t1.value = t2.value
GROUP BY t1.id,t1.value
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Left join it with GROUP BY query running on itself:

SQL Fiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b8f5/18

```
SELECT 
   tbl.id, tbl.value, cnts.counts FROM tbl
LEFT JOIN ( 
   SELECT value, COUNT(value) AS counts FROM tbl GROUP BY value
) AS cnts ON (tbl.value = cnts.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.value, t2.value FROM `table` AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    (Select value, COUNT(value)` as value 
    from table` group by value) AS t2 
   ON      (t1.value = t2.value)
GROUP by t1.Id
```